# Why don't I see the full range of a color ramp gradient after using modulo?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I'm trying to make a repeating color ramp around the outside of a cylinder (i.e., ten separate instances of black-purple-green). Unfortunately, I lose the spectrum of color ramp colours when I use the modulo function to repeat (I only get black-purple). Is there another way of doing this to get the full color ramp to repeat using a radial gradient texture?

[image]

Comment: Since no one has answered the actual question in the title, a node that takes its input modulo 0.1 will always output a result between 0 and 0.1, so you’ll always get only the first 10% of the color ramp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this setup. The key is the MAP RANGE node.

[image: MapRange]

Comment: Huge thanks! Sending good vibes your way. I haven't come across this node before.

Comment: No problem. You can play with the two lower values to "push" the gradient around a bit, but it should be good as is. Happy travels.

Answer (score 8):

If you know you're only ever going to need a 0-1 range in the segments, you can just use a multiplication .. but @Christopher's answer is more flexible.

[image]

Comment: BTW, you can up-vote his answer as well as accepting it :)